# Handling Failed to load resource errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working in a c# mvc3 application in which requirement is to log all errors,i have managed to used Application_Error event on server and window.onerror event on client side for logging most of errors.

But when any content failed to load(Like image not found on server(Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) htt//examplehost/Content/Images/notexistingimage.png)) 
then none of above event fires.

How can I know when these errors occurs so that i may log them?